# Handling null objects in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array with 18 objects in it, and the array is allocated to have 25 objects in it (the remaining 7 objects are null for future use). I’m writing a program that prints out all the non-null objects, but I’m running in to a `NullPointerException` and I can’t figure out how to get around it.

When I try this, the program crashes with `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`:

```
        for(int x = 0; x < inArray.length; x++)
        {
            if(inArray[x].getFirstName() != null)//Here we make sure a specific value is not null
            {
                writer.write(inArray[x].toString());
                writer.newLine();
            }
        }
```

And when I try this, the program runs, but still prints the nulls:

```
        for(int x = 0; x < inArray.length; x++)
        {
            if(inArray[x] != null)//Here we make sure the whole object is not null
            {
                writer.write(inArray[x].toString());
                writer.newLine();
            }
        }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for handling null objects in an array? All help is appreciated!

Comment: I am surprised that the second version doesn't work.  Are you sure it still prints the nulls?

Comment: I think Louis is correct. There is not any problem with the second version of code.

Comment: "but still prints the nulls", are you sure? Have you overrided the method `toString()` in your class?

Comment: the object is not null, but its firstname is (may be)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Maybe: `inArray[x] != null` but `inArray[x].toString()` prints null.

Comment: The second version is definitely more correct than the first - you can't call a method on a null object at all.

Comment: Well I got it working per the answer by @Habib.OSU when I combined both. Thank you!

Comment: For the record, none of the first 18 results in the array should have any null values

Comment: If you use an ArrayList instead of an array, you don't need to reserve space "for future use", and your loop becomes much simpler.

Comment: @GriffeyDog Yes, I realize that...but this was a homework assignment ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

your check should be:

```
if(inArray[x] != null && inArray[x].getFirstName() != null)
```

Comment: Thank you @Habib.OSU, I will accept this when I can. So simple, not sure why I didn't try it!